# Possible to pvmove & vgreduce in LVM if PVs are allocated to Xfs free space?

Tags: linux, filesystems, lvm, xfs

I have a ~250 TB Xfs file system, distributed across several disks (PVs) via LVM.

I've moved most of the data to another server. The remaining data (~60 TB) would easily fit on just PV.

I would like to decommission all but one disk in my VG. The trouble is my LV is an Xfs, and `Xfs filesystem shrinking is unsupported`. So no matter how “empty” the filesystem is, I can’t use `pvmove` to take extents off the PV, because it’s still being “used” by free space in Xfs, and thus can’t `vgreduce` it.

All the tutorials on how to do this, e.g. https://yallalabs.com/linux/how-to-reduce-shrink-the-size-of-a-lvm-partition-formatted-with-xfs-filesystem/ , boil down to "back up your data, reformat, restore".

Is that truly the only option?

Comment: I found https://github.com/cosmos72/fstransform but suspect nobody has ever tested xfs to ext4  (which is shrinkable) with a filesystem even remotely the size of mine.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this for xfs long back. Don't have commands handy, but did below:

1. Take backup of current XFS file system
2. Remove the LV
3. Create new LV with required size
4. Restore the XFS backup